# Finding $f(x,t)$ given $g(x'(t),t)$, and $f(x,0)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, probability-distributions, partial-derivative

Let's say there is thing with a probability distribution function $f(x,t)$ describing the probability amplitude of this thing as a function of both $x$, and of $t$.  Also this same thing has a probability distribution function $g(x'(t),t)$ describing the probability amplitude of this thing as a function of both $x'(t)$, and $t$ with $x'(t)$ being the first derivative of $x$ with respect to $t$.  Also this same thing has a probability distribution function $f(x,0)$ for the probability of this thing as a function of $x$, when $t=0$.

Given $g(x'(t),t)$, and $f(x,0)$ how do I find $f(x,t)$?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: @bjorn93 By example do you mean an example of a function for $f(x,0)$, and $g(x'(t),t)$?  An example could be for $f(x,0)$ to be gaussian, and for $g(x'(t),t)$ to be independent of $t$, and gaussian.  If possible I want an answer for the general case, in which $f(x,0)$ could be any function of $x$ at $t=0$ and for $g(x'(t),t)$ to be any function function of $x'(t)$ and $t$.